# DataGridView loses one row from Datatable in TabControl

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a application that uses a `DataGridView` sitting on a `TabPage` and a `DataTable` as Datasource. I create the `DataTable`, fills the Rows and set the `DataGridView's` Datasource to the `DataTable` on Startup. like this

```
        aData.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
        aData.Columns.Add("OID", typeof(string));
        aData.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
        aData.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Row 1", 0, null });
        aData.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Row 2", 1, null });
        aData.AcceptChanges();
        dgTest.DataSource = aData;
```

I have a thread that executes and fires an event that will update the `DataTable` value.

All works perfectly until you start to switch between the `TabPages`, then the `DataGrid` lose one of the Rows. If you click on the column header to sort the rows, then it pops back. But switch between the `TabPages` and it disappears again.

If you interogate the DataGrid, the Rows properties only show 1 row, but the `DataTable` still shows 2 rows.

I'm a bit confused on why this happen and if there is something I'm doing wrong. I've added a sample application with the same behavior [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/40qzher9b9wd63k/TestDataGridProblem.rar?dl=0)

Comment: Hmm, that's weird.. I tried your code snippet in a simple application and I am not losing any rows while iterating through tabs. Can you add an dgTest.Update() on the tab changed event, so we can make sure the UI is redrawn?

Comment: @Gnqz The code sample definitely does reproduce the problem, it just isn't always reliable and can take several tries.

Comment: If you change `Thread.Sleep(1)` to `Thread.Sleep(3000)` in `Class1.cs` it's easier to replicate. Open the form, you'll see the values are not populated. If you swap back and forth before they are the issue occurs. Once they're populated the issue doesn't occur until several tries later.

Comment: The `Thread.Sleep(1)` is actually `SnmpV1Packet result = (SnmpV1Packet)target.Request(pdu, param);` I Just put Thread.Sleep(1) to replace the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke `AcceptChanges` from the UI thread. Make the next change in your code:

```
// aData.AcceptChanges(); <- change this to the code below inside your OnResult event
this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { aData.AcceptChanges(); }));
```

Your event should now look like this:

```
void rm_OnResult(int Row, int Value)
{
    DataRow[] dr;

    dr = aData.Select("OID = '" + Row + "'");
    dr[0]["Value"] = Value.ToString("#,###.00");
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { aData.AcceptChanges(); }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Because `DataTable` didn't have an invoke, I thought it might not need it. I use invoke on the other controls because I get cross thread errors if I don't

Comment: I cannot use `BeginInvoke` on a class. So I just use `this.Invoke(new Action(() => snmpInfo.ValueControl.AcceptChanges()));`. For anybody that might have the same issue